# pass integer value from activity class to non activity class

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android studio. I need to pass integer value from activity class to non activity class in android studio.

Activity class:

```
public class Main2Activity extends Activity {
    // enter code here
 }
```

Non activity class:

```
public class GameView extends View {
  public GameView(Context context, Maze maze){                                           }
}
```

Comment: You can also use static keyword to access variable declared in Activity.

Comment: You can also change your code like
public class Main2Activity extends Activity {
    // enter code here
    int i= 5;
    public class GameView extends View {
    //enter code here
    Log.e("i", i+"");
   }
 }

Answer (score 0):

```
for simplest, use constructer
like:

public class Main2Activity extends Activity 
{

 int x=5;
 GameView view =new GameView(x)

 }


public class GameView extends View {
int y;     
GameView(int y){
this.y=y;
}
//your values has been passed

}
```

Comment: so what is next:  add another params and you can get       
   GameView(Context context, Maze maze , int y )

Comment: my GameView class already have following constructer                                                                                                                                                      public GameView(Context context, Maze maze) { }                                                                                                              
 therefore following error will display when i create GameView(int y)      . "there is no default constructor available in android.view.view "           what can i do